# How would you write "Turtle-senpai"

Tags: spelling

Would it be 亀先輩? How would you write "Turtle-Senpai"?
亀せんぱい maybe?
I have no idea how to properly add a suffix to a word/name.

Comment: As in [亀仙人](http://limerhymelife.img.jugem.jp/20110906_2678625.jpg)?

Answer (score 4):

If you're asking whether you should write "senpai" as 先輩 or せんぱい, the answer is 先輩. (If you're trying to give off a cute or childish feeling to the text you could use せんぱい, but that's not really something you'd normally do.)

I guess I should mention that you'd never use the 先輩 honorific when referring to yourself, so your handle is rather odd sounding.

Comment: lol, +1 on the handle comment :)

Comment: We have a 鼠先輩, though.  http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%BC%A0%E5%85%88%E8%BC%A9

Comment: @非回答者, wow I had no idea! Time to eat that comment I guess...